# How I should identify shared domain events (Event Sourcing) contracts between microservices?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, cqrs, event-sourcing

The problem is that I need a standard way to **serialize** and **deselialize** **domain events** between different **microservices** (either by a `unique identifier` for each `type event`), so the contract type of these messages must be agnostic to the programming language.

Is there any protocol or standard of communication between the passage of `events` between **microsrevices** in order to identify them with queues? What is the best way for you? Or some standard framework for communicating these events on `net.Core`?

Answer (score 1):

We copy the events as external events into the other services. We also use a shared event model to communicate upcoming changes to everyone. https://eventmodeling.org/posts/what-is-event-modeling/

Comment: What about Eventflow?

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of the Publisher/Subscriber model/pattern of events. Usually, an organization may define its own format of an event message, which must be followed by each publisher (domain in this case, such as Customer, Order, Product, Payment, etc.), and then the subscriber app/domain will consume the published event [if Subscribed to].

While there are many options available for implementing this, such as RabitMQ, Azure Service Bus, Azure EventHUb, and open-source Kafka or Azure Event Hubs for Apache Kafka. You may want to 1st align the pub/sub and what contract will work best for your organization (you can always evolve).

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/integration-event-based-microservice-communications for some samples of using RabitMQ if that will interest you.